# Update Manifest Version From Pom

Tags: tycho

After releasing (and I know Tycho does not support that, but we made it work somehow) I want to change the version of the *Manifest.MF* automatically from the *pom.xml* - in the future even in the same build process.

While researching for how to implement a custom Maven plug-in I found the `tycho-versions-plugin`, which almost seems to do what I want, so I added it to the build:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>versions</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-version</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
            <newVersion>${project.version}</newVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now this only works if the *Manifest.MF* and the *pom.xml* already have the same version, which is useless in my case. Is there some obscure parameter I'm missing or do I really have to develop my own plug-in for the exotic use-case of incrementing the version?

Comment: Why are the Manifest.MF and the pom.xml not the same in the beginning?
Step 1) Manifest.MF and the pom.xml have the same version
Step 2) You run your build. Perhaps set `${new.project.version}` in the `settings.xml` and use it instead of `${project.version}`
Step 3) The Manifest.MF and the pom.xml have the same updated version

This is a simplified solution, but I am not sure if I understand your problem exactely.

Comment: @gillesB Because after a (Maven) release the _pom.xml_'s version get incremented, but not the one of the _Manifest.MF_. Up until know, we need to check out the project in question and increment the version manually (or using some tools, but it's the same).

Comment: You can bring the versions back in sync with the version plugin's `update-pom` goal. Then you can call `set-version`.

Comment: @oberlies That are two manual steps and I have to remember to use the correct version, so not really an improvement from updating manually.

Comment: @oberlies It also is incorrect. It will update the POM back to the old version, prior to the maven-release-plugin incrementing the POM. That's not what is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wants to fix their own `tycho-versions-plugin`, here's what I did to make it work. In `VersionsEngine` I removed the `if` in the following method:

```
public void addVersionChange(String artifactId, String newVersion) throws IOException {
    MutablePomFile pom = getMutablePom(artifactId);

    // if (!newVersion.equals(pom.getVersion())) {
        addVersionChange(new VersionChange(pom, newVersion));
    // }
}
```

And I'm not entirely sure if that's necessary or even wise, but I changed the following method in `BundleManifestManipulator`:

```
private boolean isProjectVersionChange(ProjectMetadata project, VersionChange change) {
    MutableBundleManifest mf = getBundleManifest(project);
    return change.getArtifactId().equals(mf.getSymbolicName());
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to ask the Tycho developers if your changes are wise or not. Maybe they will add them to the next release.

Comment: @gillesB An official Tycho developer already commented: It's not necessary to update the Manifest from the _pom.xml_. That's not really surprising, since Tycho does not support releases, and if you never increment any version they cannot differ from one another. We're just in the rare and exotic position where we actually want to release every now and then. I'm just adding the code for companies that do stupid stuff like that as well.

Comment: Ugh, this issue is over 2 years old, and I'm running into the problem myself now. Tycho does not seem to be a very actively maintained project.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this post,was very useful!
There is a way of release with tycho, just have to disable version check.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>

            <configuration>
                <strictVersions>false</strictVersions>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

thanks to @Steffi S. I created a new Mojo to do such thing:
can get it at
https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/pull/7
or 
https://github.com/perelengo/tycho